# How to detect the turnover motion in android?

Tags: android, android-sensors

If the user turns over the phone I want to react to that by stopping my text to speech reading. It would be a nice feature for my app, but how can I detect this motion? I'm not really familiar with motion sensors and I could not find this specific motion listener anywhere, mostly just screen orientations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a thought: if "putting the phone face down" is OK (as opposed to just turning it over in mid-air), then detecting a sudden darkening of the ambient light might work ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_LIGHT))  Don't know if there's a listener for this.

Comment: will check it out later (on monday) if i can use that. the documentation says environment sensors are much easier to use, so i'm hopeful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample activity demonstrates how a device's gravity sensor can be used to detect when the device is turned over.  In method `onSensorChanged()`, term `factor` determines how complete the "turn over" must be.  Typical range might be 0.7 to 0.95.

Support for Gravity Sensor was added in Android API 9.  Not all devices have a gravity sensor.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Demo";

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mGravitySensor;
    private boolean mFacingDown;

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        final float factor = 0.95F;

        if (event.sensor == mGravitySensor) {
            boolean nowDown = event.values[2] < -SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * factor;
            if (nowDown != mFacingDown) {
                if (nowDown) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "UP");
                }
                mFacingDown = nowDown;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mGravitySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);

        if (mGravitySensor == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device has no gravity sensor");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGravitySensor != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGravitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i'll try it out on monday when i'm back in college, i'm doing my app as an assignment there. (not gonna forget about accepting it :)

Comment: Could you help me how could I use this (tested it, works well) in a class? I want to use it in many activites, so I thought i implement all of this in a public class, but having trouble making it work, right now I get 0 errorst, just the app wont start on my phone :O

Comment: actually the app not starting was for a whole other reason, i just had to delete it from my phone and reinstall it.

Comment: or not, when i try to use my GravitySensor class in an activity, I get this error on the "Run" tab of android studio:
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.uzoltan.readout
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

Comment: Should I use asynctask for this i guess? Right now my app freezes if i start the acvitiy which uses my GravitySensor class.

Comment: right now i implemented it in 7 activity, might just leave it this way

Comment: @Zoltán The sensor updates occur asynchronously and do not block the main thread.  I can't think of a reason you would need to use an AsyncTask.  You can create a class for the sensor processing.  The class will need methods to register and unregister the listener.  You must unregister the listener when the activity is paused or stopped, otherwise you will continue to get updates (about 5/second).  Also note that some motions to turn the phone over will also result in a configuration change (screen rotation).  In those cases, your activity will be stopped, destroyed and recreated.